# redundant code in core data initialising stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I was learning core data from apple guide when i saw the "initialize the core data stack code"

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[self managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]
```

I dont understand why do you need to get pointer to psc again in line 37 when its already been done in line 27. dosn't a block scope go all the way up to the function it is embedded in?

link for doc:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between the time the block captured the state and the time the block was executed, either the `moc` or the `psc` that needed to be operated on could have changed.

By calling `[self managedObjectContext]`, that race condition is *mostly* eliminated.   *Mostly* only because it is a concurrent queue and, thus, some other queue might muck with the `moc` or `psc` concurrently.

I.e. the code is somewhat hardened against concurrency issues.